# Logarithmic quotient

Tags: logarithms

$$
\left(\frac25\right)\ln(1/2)+\left(\frac15\right)\ln(2)
$$

Im having some difficulty with above quotient. Here is what i try to do.

$$
\left(\frac15\right)(2\ln(1/2)+\ln(2))
$$

$$
\left(\frac15\right)(\ln((1/2)^2)+\ln(2))
$$

$$
\left(\frac15\right)(\ln(1/4)+\ln(2))
$$

$$
\left(\frac15\right)(\ln(1)-\ln(4)+\ln(2))
$$

$$
\left(\frac15\right)(\ln(2)-(\ln(4))
$$

$$
\left(\frac15\right)(\ln(1/2))
$$

$$
\left(\frac15\right)(\ln(1)-\ln(2))
$$

Wolfram gets, but im not sure how $$
-3\log(2)/5
$$

Comment: Given the distinction made, what base logarithm is $\log$ here ? Also - you're missing a bracket second line up from the bottom.

Comment: are both logarithms in $\left(\frac25\right)log(1/2)+\left(\frac15\right)ln(2)$ to the same base?

Comment: yes they are the same, im used to using ln.

Comment: Much quicker to start with $\log(1/2)=-\log 2$.

Comment: @DavidMitra yes. He writes things like $\log(1/2)=\log(1)-\log(2)=-\log(2)$ I am not sure why?

Comment: @DavidMitra et al. I'm sure the OP is just learning rules of logarithm, including the log of a quotient $\ln(\frac xy) = \ln x - \ln y$. I'm sure s/he will "get" in no time that $\ln(\frac 1x) = -\ln x$.

Comment: Pierre, your work is just fine! Just simplify your "ending" answer: $\dfrac{\ln(1) - \ln (2)}{5} = \dfrac {-\ln 2}{5}$, that's all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must have mistyped the question into wolfram.  Wolfram gets the same [answer](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=2ln%280.5%29%2F5%2Bln%282%29%29%2F5) as you do.